# NLog is not sending logs to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog, amazon-cloudwatch

I am setting up NLog in my asp net core 2.1 application
But it is not generating the log on AWS, I followed the documentation, I did some tests, I was only able to generate the log.txt on localhost, however for the AWS configuration it is not working. am i doing something wrong?
follow the code:

Here is the configuration NLog

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.AWS.Logger" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="aws" type="AWSTarget" logGroup="NLog.ConfigExample" region="us-east-1"/>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Console" layout="${callsite} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile,aws" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm calling it like this:

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using NLog.Web;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using NLog.AWS.Logger;

namespace API_Coletor_Status
{
    public class Program
    {        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            ConfigureNLog();
            Logger loggerr = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            loggerr.Info("Check the AWS Console CloudWatch Logs console in us-east-1");
            loggerr.Info("to see messages in the log streams for the");
            loggerr.Info("log group NLog.ConfigExample");
        }

        static void ConfigureNLog()
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

            var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
            config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

            var awsTarget = new AWSTarget()
            {
                LogGroup = "NLog.LogPlataforma",
                Region = "us-east-1"
            };
            config.AddTarget("aws", awsTarget);

            config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));
            config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, awsTarget));

            LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
              .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
              {
                  logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                  logging.AddConsole();
                  logging.AddDebug();
                  logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
              })
              .UseNLog();   
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to add `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` as last statement in your `Main()` https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush. You can also activate the NLog InternalLogger and check for errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585490/193178

Comment: You have now generated an aws.logger.errors.txt file where you have the following error: at AWS.Logger.Core.AWSLoggerCore.LogEventTransmissionSetup (CancellationToken token) in C: \ codebuild \ tmp \ output \ src867846031 \ src \ src \ AWS.Logger .Core \ Core \ AWSLoggerCore.cs: line 438
   at AWS.Logger.Core.AWSLoggerCore.Monitor (CancellationToken token) in C: \ codebuild \ tmp \ output \ src867846031 \ src \ src \ AWS.Logger.Core \ Core \ AWSLoggerCore.cs: line 322
----

suggestion?

Comment: Instead of posting the exception as a comment. Can you update your initial question with the exception details? (So one can see Exception-Type, Exception-Message + Exception-StackTrace).