# Application Insights configuration web API

Tags: azure-application-insights, nlog, azure-web-app-service

I have created a library project for writing logs into ApplicationInsights as well as table storage and is being consumed my different other WebAPI projects. But due to some reason the logs are not getting logged in Application Insights but it works with table storage.

```
private void AddTelemetryTarget(string instrumentationKey, LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel minLogLevel, LoggingConfiguration config)
        {
            try
            {           ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition("ApplicationInsightsTarget", typeof(ApplicationInsightsTarget));
                ApplicationInsightsTarget aiTarget = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();
                aiTarget.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
                aiTarget.Name = "ai";
                var wrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper(aiTarget, 5000, AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow);
                config.AddTarget("TelemetryAsyncWrapper", wrapper);

                //Applying logging rules.
                LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", ConvertLogType(minLogLevel), aiTarget);
                config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        private LogLevel ConvertLogType(LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel.Error: return LogLevel.Error;
                case LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel.Info: return LogLevel.Info;
                case LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel.Warn: return LogLevel.Warn;
                default: return LogLevel.Trace;
            }
        }


public async Task Log(string message, LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel type, Dictionary<string, string> customParams, Exception ex = null, bool isPayload = false)
        {
            LogEventInfo eventInfo = PopulateEventInfo(message, type, customParams, ex);
            if (!isPayload)
            {
                _logger.Log(eventInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                _payloadLogger.Log(eventInfo);
            }
        }

        private LogEventInfo PopulateEventInfo(string message, LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel type, Dictionary<string, string> customParams, Exception ex = null)
        {
            LogEventInfo eventInfo = new LogEventInfo();

            eventInfo.Level = ConvertLogType(type);
            eventInfo.Message = message;
            eventInfo.LoggerName = this.GetType().ToString();
            if (ex != null)
            {
                eventInfo.Exception = ex;
            }
            else if (eventInfo.Level == LogLevel.Error)
            {
                eventInfo.Exception = new Exception(message);
            }
            //Adding custom properties to LogEventInfo to display in Application insight 
            if (customParams != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in customParams)
                {
                    eventInfo.Properties.Add(param.Key, param.Value);
                }
            }
            return eventInfo;
        }
```

Version of Nuget packages are

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget : 2.13.1
NLog : 4.6.8

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the NLog InternalLogging for any interesting output? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: I will try and will update you. But interestingly I can't find a Nlog.config file in any of my project folders.

Comment: It makes sense since you are builing the NLog-config manually in your method `AddTelemetryTarget`.

Comment: That's what I read too, when I googled for any reason why it is failing. Anyway let me try the internal log now

Comment: Just to confirm, If i enable file internal log it , NLog will write trace to that text file as mentioned in the example

Comment: NLog can redirect its InternalLogger output to lots of places, but only if you configure it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585340/programmatic-configuration-of-nlog-internal-logger

Comment: Yeah. I confirmed like this , and also i enabled throw error in LogManager

Comment: Yeah. I confirmed like this , and also i enabled throw error in LogManager
public async Task Log(string message, LoggerEnumerations.LogLevel type, Dictionary<string, string> customParams, Exception ex = null, bool isPayload = false){LogEventInfo eventInfo = PopulateEventInfo(message, type, customParams, ex);     InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;            InternalLogger.LogFile = "c:\\log.txt";      InternalLogger.LogToConsoleError = true; TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"D:\R.txt");InternalLogger.LogWriter = writer;InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Trace;logger.Log(eventInfo);}

Comment: The idea is to activate the NLog InternalLogger before loading and initializing the NLog-config. Not while logging. Anyway when you get to a point where you have some actual output from the internal-logger, then you can update your question with the extra details. Happy logging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208522/discussion-between-arjun-menon-and-rolf-kristensen).

Answer (score 1):

I added Application Insights as Connected Services and I removed the Instrumentation Key from ApplicationInsights.config file and when registering the nlog target I used instrumentation key from my web.config file and it started working.